# Converting std::list<int> iterator to an CString (MFC)

Tags: c++, combobox, mfc, c++98, stdlist

Newbie in world of MFC and MS Windows C++.

I am trying to populate a ComboBox dynamically. But I am not able to convert the iterator pointer to CString or an std::string. Here is my sample code:

```
bool single_digit (const int& value) { return (value >= 60); }

int numArr[] = {10,20,30,40};
int size = sizeof(numArr)/sizeof(numArr[0]);
std::list<int> numList (numArr, numArr+size);
numList.remove_if(single_digit);

for(std::list<int>::iterator it=numList.begin(); it!=numList.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << ' ' <<*it;
   /*
   std::string s2(*it); //Not sure of conversion to CString or std::string.
   string *pelement = &*it;
  */
   //End goal: _ccomboBoxnumType.AddString(*it);
}
```

Can anyone please suggest any other STL to satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Check [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=msvc-170) out if you wants to convert `std::string` to `CString`.

Comment: Are you sure about the [tag:c++98] tag? That would mean you're using a compiler that's easily 15 years old.

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: That's unfortunate indeed, as that restriction came in 1 minute prior to me submitting an answer. That answer requires C++11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially asking how to convert an integer to its string representation. The simplest way to go about this is to call [`std::to_wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring), that provides an overload taking an `int` value.

The following code does what you're looking for:

```cpp
for(std::list<int>::iterator it=numList.begin(); it!=numList.end(); ++it)
{
   // Get value by dereferencing the iterator
   int value = *it;
   // Convert integer to string
   std::wstring display = std::to_wstring(value);
   // Extract a C-style string pointer compatible with the interface
   wchar_t const* ptr = display.c_str();
   _ccomboBoxnumType.AddString(ptr);
}
```

Of course, you should be using a range-based for loop instead, i.e.

```cpp
for(auto value : numList)
{
   _ccomboBoxnumType.AddString(std::to_wstring(value).c_str());
}
```

In case this doesn't compile make sure to set the character set to `Unicode` in the project settings. There's no reason not to.

### Update to account for the C++98 requirement

`std::to_wstring` requires C++11. If that is not something that's available to you, you can get the same functionality through e.g. MFC's [`CString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class) type by using its [`Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#format) member. Things get slightly more verbose, but not much:

```cpp
for(std::list<int>::iterator it=numList.begin(); it!=numList.end(); ++it)
{
   // Get value by dereferencing the iterator
   int value = *it;
   // Convert integer to CString
   CString display;
   display.Format(_T("%d"), value);
   // CString can implicitly be converted to LPCTSTR
   // If you like explicit, pass `display.GetString()` instead
   _ccomboBoxnumType.AddString(display);
}
```

Note that this is using [generic-text mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/generic-text-mappings) (in [disguise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/using-cstring)), a holdover from the days when targeting both Windows NT and Windows 9x was relevant. It is not recommended today, but should fit right in to a code base that requires a C++98 compiler.

---

A few recommendations to follow:

- A [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) has unique properties (such as constant time insertion and splicing), at the expense of having to allocate each element on the heap. Since you don't care about any of this, use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.
- If you need to get the integer value back (e.g. in response to user input) you can store that value inside the Combo Box item. There's [`CComboBox::SetItemData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccombobox-class#setitemdata) for that. Alternatively use a `CComboBoxEx` instead, and set both the text and data in one go by calling [`CComboBoxEx::InsertItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccomboboxex-class#insertitem).
- Another approach would be setting the item data only, and request the control to retrieve a string representation on demand. That, too, requires using a `CComboBoxEx` and setting `pszText` to [`LPSTR_TEXTCALLBACK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-comboboxexitemw) in the `InsertItem` call. The control parent is now responsible for handling the [`CBEN_GETDISPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cben-getdispinfo) notification, producing a string representation for the given item.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting [link]error C2668. std::to_wstring ambiguous call to overloaded function[link].

Comment: You're going to have to [ask john](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541155/1889329) about that. I was suggesting to call `std::to_wstring`, not `std::to_string`.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, strangely for this line: std::wstring display = std::to_wstring(value); I am getting the same error.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/jMWr3We7K) the error. Have you included all required header files (`<string>`, `<list>`, ...)? Also, what's the *full* error diagnostic? (If you want to share a link, click on the "Help" link at the bottom right of the comment editor.)

Comment: Yes I included all headers. I think its coming from the predicate. Here is the another error during compilation. Error C3867: function call missing argument list, use '&DlgWindow::single_digit'.

Comment: That's an unrelated issue. Either make `single_digit` a `static` class member, or make it a free function (as in my Compiler Explorer example). It's difficult to diagnose issues without a [mcve].

Comment: Yes no errors great! Can you provide an example for the static predicate issue, trying to understand the functors concept!

Comment: Feel free to [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that. It is unrelated to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Easy one.

```
std::string s2 = std::to_string(*it);
```

Seems your code could be a lot simpler though, there is no need to construct a list

```
for (int i : numArr)
{
    std::string s2 = std::to_string(i);
    ...
}
```